# Shellscript unary operator expected, tried many solutions none work

Tags: shell, if-statement, unix, unary-operator

I keep getting this error in my if statement, and I've tried double brackets or putting quotes around the variable or trying different operators (-eq, =, ==) but none of it works, can somebody give me a simple solution please?

Code:

```
echo "   Math Is Fun! Take a challenge..."
echo "-----------------------------------"
echo "1. Addition problem"
echo "2. Subtraction problem"
echo "3. Multiplication problem"
echo "-----------------------------------"
echo "Please input your menu option (enter Q or q to quit)"
read usr_option

while [ 0 ]
do
case $usr_option in
[1])
max=500
min=1
rnum1=$(((RANDOM % (max - min + 1)) +min))
rnum2=$(((RANDOM % (max - min + 1)) +min))
answer=$(($rnum1+$rnum2))
echo "$rnum1 + $rnum2 = "
read $usr_answer
if [ $usr_answer -eq $answer ];then
echo "Congratulations! That is right. "
else
echo "Sorry, the correct answer is $answer"
fi
echo "   Math Is Fun! Take a challenge..."
echo "-----------------------------------"
echo "1. Addition problem"
echo "2. Subtraction problem"
echo "3. Multiplication problem"
echo "-----------------------------------"
echo "Please input your menu option (enter Q or q to quit)"
read usr_option
;;
esac
done
```

Sample output:

```
Math Is Fun! Take a challenge...
------------------------------------
1. Addition problem
2. Subtraction problem
3. Multiplication problem
------------------------------------
Please input your menu option (enter Q or q to quit)

1

153 + 160 =
313

/home/~~~~~~: [: -eq: unary operator expected

Sorry, the correct answer is 313
```

When I add quotes around the variables in the if statement, it instead gives me the error integer expression expected.

Comment: It has to be `read usr_answer`, and not `read $usr_answer`. Paste your script with the correct shebang line into https://www.shellcheck.net/ and fix everything it tells you.

Comment: You should also quote all expansions.

Comment: That seemed to have fixed it, I knew it was a small mistake as always. By the way, by quoting expansions are you talking about editing the code in stackoverflow? Also thanks for the link, its very helpful. :)

Comment: (bash) Expansions: [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html). Quoting: [Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html). Use `"$quoted $variables"` in conditionals, or expanding them may break the syntax of your script. Also, could you put your terminal output into a code block so that it doesn't get Markdown-formatted?